# Spark get one row from every parquet file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have large amount of data (12 GB, compressed) partitioned in parquet files (about 2000 files, every partition has 10 files).

I want to get one row from every parquet file and do it in parallel, not just on the driver. I do not care which row I get but it is important to get a record from every file.

I have come up with this code but it is very slow.

```scala
val df = spark.read.parquet("/path/to/parquet/")
    .groupBy(input_file_name().as("fileUri")).agg(
      first("myColumn").as("myColumnValue")
    )
    .collect()
```

Comment: Not really a Spark use case.

Comment: collect() brings all the data to master node, hence this code runs slow, try not using collect and it should it be distributed to each machine since its already an rdd.

Comment: This is definitely not because of `collect()`. It is just bringing around 2000 rows to the driver, which is not many. The execution of this code takes like 5 minutes to execute on a pretty powerful cluster

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to get a `List[String]` of every parquet file, you should be able to convert each file into a `Dataframe`, and then use the `limit(1)` function to get precisely one row from each of those files. Then you can operate on the Dataframes within the executors, knowing that they each are just of length 1.

```scala
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

val fileNames: Seq[string] = ...

val dfs: Seq[Dataframe] = fileNames.map{ file => 
   spark.read
        .parquet(file)
        .toDf()
        .limit(1) 
}
```

Furthermore, if you'd like to just be able to use the rich library available for Dataframes and not have to iterate over every single one by doing `dfs.foreach(...)`, you can combine a `Seq[Dataframe]` into just one dataframe by using the `reduce` with the `union` functions:

```scala
val df : Dataframe = dfs.reduce(_ union _)
```

*note that if you do this and plan on running multiple operations on your `df` after the `reduce` you must call `df.persist(...)` , otherwise every single operation you run on `df` (like a `map` or a `sum`) will repeat the entirety of `reduce` *each* time.

the `.collect()` operations is what's slowing you down here. That's creating exactly one call on each row and sending the data over the wire back to the driver.

Comment: This looks OK-ish but it literally creates one job for every file and in case you have 2000 files it means 2000 jobs. Not sure if spark can do better than this.

Comment: To be fair, OP's use case is kind of odd. 2,000 files isn't that many realistically, and they'd be better off doing this all in the driver with simple I/O rather than Spark.

Comment: The problem is that parquet files consist of compressed blocks of data. To get even one row of data you need to read a block from the file on disk and decompress it. If you try to do it on a single machine you'll quickly run into CPU, network, and maybe even disk bottlenecks.

Comment: That's true, again why I say the use-case is weird. I'm used to parquet being many small-ish files (even compressed), due to them being written from Spark in a distributed way in the first place. I would again question _why_ OP needs one row from each parquet file on its own.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can store some hashCode like `hash(fileUri)` instead of carrying entire path, will reduce amount of data shuffled which right now is `fileUri + myColumn` for each record in `"/path/to/parquet/"`.

`PS`: this code runs on all executors in parallel, just `.collect()` part creates driver bottleneck.

Comment: This is not because of the collect. If you just execute `df.limit(2000).collect()` it takes 1 second.

Comment: Yea, I am saying that everything is running in parallel, just `.collect()` is the only thing running on driver. `.collect()` is not a problem here, I think amount of data shuffled is (which is usually the case).

Comment: Yes, I think shuffle is the problem, but logically there should not be shuffle involved because every file can be accessed just from one executor. But I guess spark is not smart enough

Comment: Yes, 1 file is read form 1 executor only but there are 2000 files and `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is by default 200 (if you have not changed) which means 10 files' data should come in a single partition (single machine), hence shuffle.